# How to add quotes around a return value of a function in PHP

Tags: php, json

This is what I have right now which works, but I need quotes around the numbers of the `id` and `total` subscript of the array. I need it to look like this:

```
{"id":"528", "total":"5280"}
```

Here's my PHP code that generates the json array:

```
    else if(strcmp($_GET['action'], 'update') == 0)
    {
        $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
        $array = array(
            'id' => $cart->count(),
            'total' => $cart->total()
        );

        echo json_encode($array);
    }
```

What it currently echos out:

```
{"id":528, "total":5280}
```

I've tried adding quotes around `$cart->count()` and `$cart->total()` manually by doing `'$cart->count()'` and `'$cart->total()'` but it literally returns the string the quotes are around. The reason I need quotes around the `id` and `total` because when I try to display them in javascript, it says undefined.

EDIT:

here's my javascript code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'includes/actionhandler.php',
    data: { action: 'update'},
    success: function (data) {
        var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        var obj = jQuery.toJSON(json)
        alert(obj['total']);
    },
});
```

Comment: This shouldn't return `undefined` in JavaScript. Can you show the output and the exact property where is complains about it being undefined?

Comment: why would it return undefined, are you outputting it using ajax? If yes, set the return dataType attribute to json and see. Otherwise wrap it on both ends with the desired character .

Comment: So in essence you want the values as strings? Why not say so and not mislead me into thinking you want quotes wrapped around it

Comment: Wow @themosquitokiller thanks for the suggestion, if you wanted to make an answer I'll accept it because, I should have just used `dataType: 'json'` instead of just trying to parse the json myself. @ all of the other answers. The real solution was adding the `dataType: 'json'` since it doesn't matter if it's an int/string.

Comment: @SieuPhan - Been through it  once, had added an answer before and deleted thinking it was something else. Undeleted it now, mark it answered, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you outputting it using ajax? If yes, set the return dataType attribute to json using -

```
            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               data: {},
               dataType:"json",
               url: '',
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = array(
  'id' => strval($cart->count()),
  'total' => strval($cart->total())
);
```

It is a workaround but will work :P

Comment: unfortunately I already tried that and I get double quotes and slashes. `{"id":"\"529\"","total":"\"5290\""}`

Comment: Oh, think i got it now. Hold on a sec

Comment: See my edit. Your problem was that the JSON was being sent with the numbers as INT. You didn't _exactly_ need quotes. You needed a `string` type ;)

Comment: Instead of `strval($cart->count())` you could use `(string)$cart->count()` to make it more human-readable ;)

Answer (score -2):

```
$array = array(
            'id' => '"'.strval($cart->count()).'"',
            'total' => '"'.strval($cart->total()).'"'
        );
```